# Как получить productSluge из api.get_free_games()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я создаю дискорд бота, который по запросу выдаёт бесплатные на данный момент игры из EpicGame Store. За основу взял код из примера и переделал под вывод бота. В footer хочу положить ссылку на страницу для получения игры. Для этого мне нужно получить "productSluge" из api.get_free_games() или получить ссылку иным способом.

Так не работает

```
api.get_free_games()['productSluge']
```

Использую epicstore_api

Мне нужна часть в скобках

https://www.epicgames.com/store/ru/product/<Эта часть>/home

Или полная ссылка

Полная команда дискорд бота:

```
@bot.command()
async def free(ctx):
    """Fetches current free games from the store."""
    api = EpicGamesStoreAPI()
    free_games = api.get_free_games()['data']['Catalog']['searchStore']['elements']
    for game in free_games:
        game_name = game['title']
        game_thumbnail = None
        # Can be useful when you need to also show the thumbnail of the game.
        # Like in Discord's embeds for example, or anything else.
        # Here I showed it just as example and won't use it.
        for image in game['keyImages']:
            if image['type'] == 'Thumbnail':
                game_thumbnail = image['url']
                # print(game_thumbnail)
        game_price = game['price']['totalPrice']['fmtPrice']['originalPrice']
        game_promotions = game['promotions']['promotionalOffers']
        upcoming_promotions = game['promotions']['upcomingPromotionalOffers']
        if not game_promotions and upcoming_promotions:
            # Promotion is not active yet, but will be active soon.
            promotion_data = upcoming_promotions[0]['promotionalOffers'][0]
            start_date_iso, end_date_iso = (
                promotion_data['startDate'][:-1], promotion_data['endDate'][:-1]
            )
            # Remove the last "Z" character so Python's datetime can parse it.
            start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(start_date_iso)
            end_date = datetime.fromisoformat(end_date_iso)

            will = ('Игра будет бесплатна с {} по {} UTC.'.format(
                start_date, end_date
            ))
            emb = discord.Embed(title=game_name + game_price, description=will, colour=col['AQUA'])
            emb.set_footer(text='url')
            emb.set_image(url=game_thumbnail)
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        else:
            emb = discord.Embed(title='Сейчас БЕСПЛАТНО!', description=game_name + game_price, colour=col['GOLD'])
            emb.set_footer(text='url')
            emb.set_image(url=game_thumbnail)
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Добавьте больше кода и более конкретно опишите что вам нужно получить

Comment: @5c0rp добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает если добавить в цикл

```
for game in free_games:
    game_slug = game['productSlug']
```